# Загрузка данных пропускаемого фрагмента при переходе через фрагмент

Tags: java, android, navigation, bundles

Возможно ли загрузить данные пропускаемого фрагмента или подгрузить при нажатии назад при обработке Bundle в OnCreate MainActivity и навигации при помощи Action, минуя один фрагмент?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вполне ясна ваша задача и проблема. Возможно, вам надо программно отображать стартовый фрагмент, программно же ему прописывая нужные аргументы?

Comment: можно общие данные держать во ViewModel и тогда не придется изобретать велосипед

Comment: Обработка bundles происходит в методе OnCreate MainActivity. Там же происходит переход на другой фрагмент при помощи Action. При таком подходе данные первого фрагмента не загружаются, а переход осуществляется сразу к другому фрагменту.